# How to customize html table border?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a table in which the border will appear like a login box.

```
<table border="1">
 <tr>
  <td>Username: </td>
  <td><input type="text" name="username" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Password: </td>
  <td><input type="password" name="password" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><input type="submit" value="Log In" /></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

What happens is that even the table cells have border and the border sucks. I want to remove cell border. The border should only be wrapping around the table. I am totally new to this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
.loginbox {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid
}
</style>

<table class="loginbox">
 <tr>
  <td>Username: </td>
  <td><input type="text" name="username" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Password: </td>
  <td><input type="password" name="password" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Log In" /></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

FYI: I added `colspan="2"` to your last `<td>` in order to make the border go all the way around.

Comment: @Son of Man: You're welcome. Please mark this answer correct by clicking the checkbox to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the following css,

```
table {
    border: thin solid black;
}
```

that will give you a border around the table only, you can see a jsfiddle for it at http://jsfiddle.net/2CdwW/

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS to put the border on the table instead:

```
<table style="border: 1px solid black">
    <tr>
            <td>Username: </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="username" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
            <td>Password: </td>
            <td><input type="password" name="password" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Log In" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```